# First Buddhist text translated into a Western language

Tags: history, texts

As a follow-up to [another question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/what-was-the-first-buddhist-text-to-be-translated-into-english):

What was the first Buddhist text to be translated into a Western language? (That probably means French or Latin, but other options are also possible)

When was it translated and by whom? Was it reasonably available to those interested and did it have much of an impact within academic circles and perhaps to the wider culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Greek versions of several of Askoka's inscriptions, erected during Ashoka's lifetime. He died in 232 BC.

Answer (score 1):

`The Dhammapada: Being a collection of moral verses in Pali (trans. into Latin) (Copenhagen, 1855) by [Viggo Fausböll][1]` seems to be the earliest Theravada text i have found so far. This was the basis of the translation by [Max Müller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_M%C3%BCller) in the [Sacred Books of the East](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_Books_of_the_East) series. This question: [What was the first Buddhist text to be translated into English?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/what-was-the-first-buddhist-text-to-be-translated-into-english) cites some Mahayana sources also throug restricted to the English language.